# Android 2.3.3 | Differentiating Intents That Start an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In Android 2.3.3, how does one differentiate Intents that start a particular Activity. For example, if both Activity_A and Activity_B have intents that call startActivityForResult( intent, requestCode), how does Activity_C differentiate between which Activity has started it? Also, I know that one passes a requestCode to the starting Activity, but how does this Activity handle the requestCode? There is no method in Intent that says getRequestCode(). Is the only way to do this to place the requestCode in a Bundle in addition to the method startActivityForResult? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

One solution would be to pass along an extra piece of identifying data. For example:

```
intent.putExtra("activity", "com.whatever.MyActivity");
```

Then the receiving Activity can read it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String activityName = extras.getString("activity");
```

It seems like there should be an easy method call to tell what the sending Intent was, but if so, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: I ended up doing this. Thanks!